# Create a new Dataframe based on conditions from another Dataframe for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

Working with 2017 NFL Quarterback Data, looking to put the top 10 qbs each week in a dataframe (along with the rest of the data).

```
qb = {'week': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'qb': ['Rodgers', 'Brady', 'Wilson', 'Rodgers', 'Brady', 'Wilson'], 'pts': [30, 24, 20, 31, 20, 26]}

qb_df = pd.DataFrame(data=qb)

week    qb        pts
1       Rodgers   30
1       Brady     24
1       Wilson    20
2       Rodgers   31
2       Brady     20
3       Wilson    26
```

For this sake looking to return the top 2 from each week into a new dataframe.

```
week    qb        pts
1       Rodgers   30
1       Brady     24
2       Rodgers   31
2       Wilson    26
```

I tried a for loop that works as far as getting the data, but can't figure out to put it in a dataframe

```
top10_17 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 18):
    i_17 = qb_2017.loc[qb_2017['Week'] == i].sort_values('FantasyPoints', ascending=False)[:10]
    top10_17 = pd.concat(i_17)
```

Used range(1,18) for the 17 weeks in an NFL season

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `sort_values` with `groupby` + `head`

```
df.sort_values('pts',ascending=False).groupby('week').head(2).sort_values('week')
Out[49]: 
   pts       qb  week
0   30  Rodgers     1
1   24    Brady     1
3   31  Rodgers     2
5   26   Wilson     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grouped = qb_df.groupby('week')
print(grouped.head(2))
```

This assumes your list is sorted, which can be done with `pandas.sort_values()`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
qb_df.set_index('qb').groupby('week')['pts'].nlargest(2)

week  qb     
1     Rodgers    30
      Brady      24
2     Rodgers    31
      Wilson     26
Name: pts, dtype: int64
```

If format is really important to stay constant:

```
qb_df.set_index('qb').groupby('week')['pts'].nlargest(2).reset_index()

week       qb  pts
0     1  Rodgers   30
1     1    Brady   24
2     2  Rodgers   31
3     2   Wilson   26
```